# CSS List Navigation: Align All Items Left, but Last Item Right

Tags: css, navigation

I've got a simple list driven navigation that looks like this:

```
Page 1    Page 2    Page 3    My Account
```

I need 'My Account' to float right:

```
Page 1    Page 2    Page 3                                                      My Account
```

Here's the list:

```
<nav class="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Page 1</li>
        <li>Page 2</li>
        <li>Page 3</li>
        <li>My Account</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I added a float:right to the last list item, and that looked great originally, until I shrunk the screen down a little.  But then it forced the first three items down a little, so 'My Account' was still aligned right, but sitting up a little higher than the other three. Like this:

```
                                       My Account
Page 1    Page 2    Page 3
```

**Edit After:**

The actual list is more complex than what I posted above. It's got dropdowns and lots of styling.  Here's the CSS:

```
.nav, .menu {
    height: 54px;
}

.nav {
    background: #004F9D;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.nav ul ul {
    background: white;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    min-width: 160px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    position: relative;
}

.nav ul ul li a {
    color: black;
}   

.nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #428BCA;
}

.menu {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.menu li {
    clear: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.menu li img {
    padding-right:10px;
}

.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #00aedd;
}

.menu a, .menu span {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.menu span {
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Add your css styles also

Comment: Can you show us your CSS please. `float:right` seems to work fine.

Comment: Ok, I'll add the CSS.  Much of it is just colors and backgrounds.

Comment: Do they all need to be in one div?

Comment: [Seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/gw5qu7z8/1/)

Comment: Carl, no.  They do not all need to be in one div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using the css alignment property, [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes). Its a little bit cleaner than using floats because it keeps everything in document flow. Just note it supports IE browsers 9 and up

```
.menu {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu li:not(:last-of-type) {
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.menu li:last-of-type {
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ujthrfcr/2)

Comment: Wow!  That worked like a charm!  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as I can. Thanks!!!

Comment: @CaseyCrookston glad to hear that the solution works for you,

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go something like this is to divide the entire div into equal parts, and use `text-align: center;` for the first 3 items, and `text-align: right` to the last one. Do not use `float:left`, and `float:right` because it messes the responsive nature of the site.